# Django unzip a file, add contents to database

Tags: python, database, django, os.walk

I am trying to create a system that enables the admin to upload a zipfile, then the script will automatically, using `signals`, unzip it, search for all the files in  `jpg,png`. create a `list`  of them and generate a database record according to it.

In models, i have `Project` and `Photo` table, `Photo` has `Many-to-One` aka `Foreign Key` relationship with `Project`.

The script below is with the signal i am working. I can get `instance.file_zip.path` without errors, and the script works well when run manually.

Long-time debugging and I assume that there is something wrong with `belongs_to=instance` but I do not know how to fix it as I didn't actually understand why it gaves an error.
The extraction part works fine, I just put them here for reference, most likely you will not need to read and understand it.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def unzip_and_process(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    #project_zip = FieldFile.open(file_zip, mode='rb')
    file_path = instance.file_zip.path
    file_list = []
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as project_zip:
        project_zip.extractall(re.search('[^\s]+(?=\.zip)', file_path).group(0))
        project_zip.close()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
        for filename in files:
            file_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    photo_list = filter(filter_photos, file_list)
    for photo in photo_list:
        print 'Processing %s'%photo
        p = Photo.objects.create(belongs_to=instance, img=photo, desc='Processed from zipfile')
        p.save()
```

**update**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name=models.CharField(max_length=150)
    date_taken=models.DateField()
    date_deadline=models.DateField()
    price=models.FloatField()
    price_paid=models.BooleanField()
    owner=models.ForeignKey(User)
    file_zip=models.FileField(upload_to='projects/%Y/%m/%d')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.project_name

    def file_path(self):
        return re.search('[^\s]+(?=\.zip)', self.file_zip.name).group(0)

class Photo(models.Model):

    def project_path(instance, filename):
        return '%s/%s'%(instance.belongs_to.file_path(),filename)

    belongs_to=models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name="related_project")
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to=project_path, max_length=255)
    desc=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s FROM [%s]'%(self.img.name,self.belongs_to)
```

Comment: Add whatever the error is to your post. Also add any other code that is actually related to the error, like `post_save` or `Project`.

Comment: It's connected to a signal which makes a silent error. No errors show up but it does not create a database entry, but it makes extraction and filelisting/filtering. I'm pretty sure that Project class is irrelevant, but I'm adding it in a second.

Comment: Why would you ever use `ZipFile.extractall()`?

Comment: To extract all files from a zipfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(file_path):
```

`file_path` refers to a `zip` file. not a `directory` hence `os.walk` returns nothing

Answer (score 2):

django-photologue has something extractly what you want, and they created a similiar hack to upload zipfile.

Link: http://code.google.com/p/django-photologue/ incase you don't want to google

Evenmore, the zip uploading class is GalleryUpload(models.Model)

Comment: This is almost same thing I've been trying to write. Well, it might be better to check it out and edit on my demands. Cheers.